# Flutter Build Error: "Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[19.7.0]."

Tags: flutter, maven, google-play-services, bintray

Recently i get the following build error on flutter:

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[19.7.0].
> Required by:
> project :app > project :google_mobile_ads > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0
> project :app > project :google_mobile_ads > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:19.7.0
> project :app > project :google_mobile_ads > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:19.7.0
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-base/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-base/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-base/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

I believe this is due to bintray being depreciated. This is my android/build.gradle

```html
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()

//        jcenter()

//        maven {
//            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'
//        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
//
//        jcenter()

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have replaced jcenter with mavenCentral, cleared cache and ran flutter clean but i still receive the same error

This is my app level build.gradle:

```html
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29 // used to be 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.eventr_app_2021"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.0.0' //used to be 17.4.0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Work around for onesignal-gradle-plugin compatibility
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = 
true
```